# How to show the project structure correctly in IntelliJ?

Tags: intellij-idea

Do you know how to show project structure correctly?

My Project structures can't show all my files.

I don't know how to fix it.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Which kind of files are missing? Can you provide a screenshot of the file structure in an explorer vs the structure in IntelliJ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure that the content root of your module is at the root level of your project (in Project settings). Then mark any folder containing source code as Sources (and similarly folders containing tests as Test Sources).